# Angular4 - Change state from component not template

Tags: router, angular

In AngularJS I used ui-router for redirecting inside of my app(changing state).

It has 2 possible options to redirect

- In template `ui-sref='stateName'`
- In controller `$state.go()`

I just start play with Angular (4) and I found only way how to change route from template with something like:

- Template `routerLink="routePath"`

Is there some way as there was in ui-router to change route from component?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
constructor(private router:Router) {}

changeRoute() {
  this.router.navigate(...)
  // this.router.navigateByUrl(...)
}
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html

Answer (score 1):

you can navigate via router like this

```
router.navigate([URL])
```

or like this

```
router.navigateByUrl('whole_string_containing_full_path')
```

Here router is an instance created in constructor, which is imported from router firstly, basically there is no  difference between these two

First one accept array where as second one accept url in the form of string.